# How to reset the admin password on VM on Windows Azure?

Tags: azure

The virtual machines on Windows Azure allow to connect [from RDP](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/log-on-a-windows-vm/). But how can I reset the administrator password if the password has been lost?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is an option now in https://portal.azure.com/ You need to log in with your Azure credentials. Browse -> Virtual Machines -> Select Your Virtual Machine -> Select Setting on top -> Password Reset

Comment: Would you mind adding a few pictures I am at settings but i don't see anything about resetting the password.

Comment: After you click on the Virtual Machine, click on "Diagnose and solve problems" and scroll down to the "Tools" section. The "Reset password" link is under there.

Comment: What is the difference between changing the password inside the VM vs via portal(as you showed?) ?

Answer (score 5):

https://portal.azure.com/#  >  on left, "Virtual machines" and not Virtual machines (classic)   >  line with your VM  >  Reset password at bottom of middle column, under SUPPORT + TROUBLESHOOTING  > Eureka!

Takes a minute or so.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can with PowerShell's help. For more details read ["Microsoft Azure Virtual Machines: Reset Forgotten Admin Passwords with Windows PowerShell"](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2014/04/03/microsoft-azure-virtual-machines-reset-forgotten-admin-password-with-windows-powershell.aspx).

```
Import-Module Azure

$subscriptionName = "Windows Azure MSDN - Visual Studio Ultimate"
$cloudSvcName = "ChangeThisWithYourVMServiceName"
$VMname = "ChangeThisWithYourVMName"

Select-AzureSubscription -Current $subscriptionName
Get-AzureSubscription | Format-Table –Property SubscriptionName
$adminCredentials = Get-Credential -Message "Enter new credentials"
$virtualMachine = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $cloudSvcName -Name $VMname
    If ($virtualMachine.VM.ProvisionGuestAgent) {
        Set-AzureVMAccessExtension -VM $virtualMachine `
            -UserName $adminCredentials.UserName `
            -Password $adminCredentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password `
            -ReferenceName "VMAccessAgent" | 
        Update-AzureVM
        Restart-AzureVM -ServiceName $virtualMachine.ServiceName -Name $virtualMachine.Name
    } else {
        Write-Output "$($virtualMachine.Name): VM Agent Not Installed"
    }
```

Comment: It will work only if provision agent is installed. If you do not have provision agent installed you are screwed.

Comment: I got problems with the `Select-AzureSubscription` and followed this advice to store my credentials: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817539/argumentnullexception-get-azureservice 
For those how are unsure what the variables should look like: Just issue `Get-AzureVM` and a listing of all VMs is shown

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this now, but you can get the data off of the drive if you need to.  Please see the Microsoft answer here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nb-NO/WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork/thread/92a55a09-19c9-4731-b7a6-2b1a9ea909f7